# Automatically load postrequisite files

Tags: requirejs

I'm looking to automatically load dependant files, similarly to how `deps` works however these files need to be loaded AFTER the initially requested.

For example:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/',
  paths: {
    jquery: '/assets/components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    highcharts: '/assets/components/highcharts/highcharts.js', 
    'highcharts.more': '/assets/components/highcharts/highcharts-more.js'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: { exports: 'jQuery' },
    highcharts: { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'highcharts.more' : { deps: ['highcharts'] },
  }
});

define(function (require) {
  var app = require('assets/js/app');
  app.start();
});
```

When requiring `highcharts`, jQuery will automatically be loaded as a dependant, however Highcharts requires that you load two files.

Does anyone know how I can load postrequisite files, i.e. after loading `highcharts` to automatically load `highcharts.more`.

I could simply set `highcharts` a dependency of `highcharts-more` and load `highcharts-more` however hoped there was a cleaner way?

Hope this makes sense?!

Thanks

Gav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading `highcharts.more` and making it a dependency of `highcharts` is the way to go. You can also hide `highcharts.more` from your modules by using a `map` configuration:

```
map: {
  "*": {
    highcharts: "highcharts.more"
  },
  "highcharts.more": {
    highcharts: "highcharts"
  }
}
```

The mapping above says "in all modules (`*`) when `highcharts` is requested, load `highcharts.more` instead, but in `highcharts.more` when `highcharts` is requested load `highcharts`".

With this, you can just list `highcharts` as a dependency in your actual modules.

Comment: Hey Louis, thanks for that. I had hoped that there was a way that I could say that when I load a specific item, I can specify dependencies using `deps` but also specify a list of additional items/files that are needed. No doubt it's probably beyond the scope of require, but thought I'd chance it ;)